# How can i check my conceptual model is correct? And normalisation example

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I am designing a relational database for a project I'm involved with. I have a Entity-Relationship AND logical model but I'm not sure if they are correct or not. Are there any stone wall ways of testing the data to see if I have correctly followed the right paths, so to speak?

Here is an example can you tell me if this is correct? If so I know I am correct.

Given the following fields Galleryid, Name, Location, City, Postcode, Paintings on Display, the data-model would be

```
Gallery (GalleryID, Location, City, Postcode)
Gallery Items (GalleryID, Paintings on Display)
```

as there was repeating data in the Paintings on Display field. I think this is now in 3rd normal form?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the ER database it worth to have a look at the "[Data Base normalization rules](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)"

have also a look [here](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html) for a practical DB normalization tutorial

Regarding the logical model it is hard to say as it should be shaped around your business needs. Anyway you could be write some tests against your model to see if you can get what you are looking for.

Comment: If i give you a example of one of the tables can i tell you me if I'm on the right lines?

Comment: I have add another link which shows a practical example. I hope it helps

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. Although this system isn't a stock/customer/order system, its a art gallery system so thats why I'm struggling understanding all the relevant parts!

Answer (score 0):

The quick rules of thumb would be:

1. Don't violate the [principle of atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity). Trying to place a whole collection in  a single field will make this fields more "opaque" and less easy to properly index, query and relate to other tables.
2. And don't violate [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY). Even if you don't know anything about functional dependencies and database normalization, just looking at your model and trying to identify redundancies will tell you a great deal about your model's quality. In fact, the whole purpose of normalization is to avoid "repeating yourself".

In your particular case, assuming `Paintings on Display` is just one value (in which case it should really be called `Painting on Display`), you should be OK.

The point if interest is `Location` - what exactly does it mean and can it be repeated for multiple galleries?